# How do I make my WPF User Control's dependency properties update my view model?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I'm trying to create a user control with dependency properties to bind to. Internally I have a `ComboBox` that is bound to these same properties, but the binding only works one way. The `ComboBox` fills from the `ItemsSource`, but `SelectedItem` doesn't get updated back to the viewmodel I'm binding to.

A simplified example:

This is the view model to bind with the user control:

```
public class PeopleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        People = new List<string>( new [] {"John", "Alfred","Dave"});
        SelectedPerson = People.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private IEnumerable<string> _people;
    public IEnumerable<string> People 
    { 
        get { return _people; } 
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("People"));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _selectedPerson;
    public string SelectedPerson 
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedPerson = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPerson"));
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This is the User control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PeopleControlTest.PeopleControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="56" d:DesignWidth="637">
<StackPanel >
    <ComboBox Margin="11"
              ItemsSource="{Binding BoundPeople, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding BoundSelectedPerson, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

with code behind

```
public partial class PeopleControl : UserControl
{
    public PeopleControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPeopleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundPeople", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(PeopleControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedPersonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedPerson", typeof(string), typeof(PeopleControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    public IEnumerable<string> BoundPeople
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(BoundPeopleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BoundPeopleProperty, value); }
    }

    public string BoundSelectedPerson
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BoundSelectedPersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BoundSelectedPersonProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And this is how I bind the user control in the main window (with the windows data context set to an instance of the viewmodel)

```
<Window x:Class="PeopleControlTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PeopleControlTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <controls:PeopleControl 
            BoundPeople="{Binding People}" 
            BoundSelectedPerson="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The combobox in the user control fills with the names, but when I select a different name this doesn't get updated back to the view model. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some properties bind two-way by default (Including `SelectedItem`) but your `BoundSelectedPerson` does not. You can set the Mode of the binding:

```
   <controls:PeopleControl 
            BoundPeople="{Binding People}" 
            BoundSelectedPerson="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Or you can make it TwoWay by default by setting a flag on the `DependencyProperty`:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedPersonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedPerson", typeof(string), typeof(PeopleControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("",FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Comment: Great, thank you, that works!!!
For some reason I thought I'd read that all DPs work two way by default. I was using UIPropertyMetadata as well, on which I couldn't find that option.

Comment: _(This solution is fine. I just want to add a note for people who might have the same problem I had and find their way here while looking for a solution.)_   
  
The property that you bind to a dependency property of the UserControl must have a set() method.