# WPF UserControl property binding for some and not others

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a the following three items in my xaml that have there visibility changed depending on a boolean property located in the DataContext of the page.

```
<worklist:PhysicianQuickInsert Visibility="{Binding IsInsertingPhysician, Converter={StaticResource NullEmptyFalseToInvisibileConverter}}" />
<shared:LoadingIndicator Visibility="{Binding IsInsertingPhysician, Converter={StaticResource NullEmptyFalseToInvisibileConverter}}" />
<TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsInsertingPhysician, Converter={StaticResource NullEmptyFalseToInvisibileConverter}}" />
```

The TextBlock and LoadingIndicator are becoming visible/collapsed, but the PhysicianQuickInsert fails to do anything.

I have verified that the getter of the boolean property is never retrieved for the PhysicianQuickInsert.

Why would this happen? PhysicianQuickInsert is a usercontrol, as is the LoadingingIndicator.

Comment: Did you look at the output window for binding errors?

Comment: Does the getter for IsInsertingPhysician get called at all?

Comment: Get getter is getting called 2 times (for the LoadingIndicator and TextBlock). If I remove these 2, the getter never gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments on my answer, this issue was that this user control binds to a another datacontext (different type) within it. I added a RelativeSource and it worked.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you defined a new `Visibility` property on your `UserControl`.  If you've done this, you may need to make sure that it's [binding two-way by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887243/65358), has a proper setter, etc.